# Recover LUKS partition of flash drive that (should) still have header

Tags: partition-recovery, luks

On an flash drive with 7.1 GB useable storage, I had a LUKS partition (2nd partition) of around 3.1GB, IIRC. A linux FS flashing using balena deleted that and the 1st partition, with the OS partition flashed is 2.2GB. (At end of post is how that seemed to have happened, which I am at a loss for—not directly relevant though.)

If the above is not drastically incorrect (doubtful), the 2nd partition including its header should be recoverable. … I started doing some internet querying but stopped—I pretty much never make ‘what do pls help??’ posts when it comes to linux and generally speaking, but in this case, the partition is quite valuable to me. It isn’t worth risking a mistake due to doing something informed by a resource not fully aligned with my set of circumstances. Note that while I do have a recent backup, it’s not recent enough to have negated impact of having deleted the original.

**The Request for Guidance:**
I’ll be using an live Arch-based distro for attempting recovery (can use different OS, though I take it that isn’t necessary).
I’d like to ask readers’ for guidance how to confirm the LUKS partition is intact and then attempt it’s recovery with high degree of risk aversion. The current partition table is DOS, with the 2.2G FS and a 4M boot partition; the original partition table was GPT.
Any inputs would be greatly appreciated.

*[not important to above request]
**Annex1-balenaEtcher fuckery?**
~TL;DR 2 attempts to flash different drive with ‘Luks’ drive plugged in noted as failed, with a shutdown of Win, booted into later on with possibly saved balena Session, and only the Luks drive plugged in, not orig. target. Discovery: both drives somehow flashed successfully*
I’ve flashed a disk dozens of times with rufus/balena. In this case, I was trying to flash a different, exFAT 28gb flash drive. I had on it just one small file, which was deleted before using disk part to clean the drive and then proceeding to attempt the flash. It got most/all of the way thru flashing then validating before saying failed. I had to go do. something AFK for a bit so was like ¯_(ツ)_/¯ classic diskpart/subpar Windows disk capabilities (fdisk has never failed me for wiping drives to reformat while Windows has several times) so IIRC I started a 2nd flash attempt.

Now, from the first attempt, the flash drive with the deleted LUKS partition was mounted this whole time. However, I’m all but certain I did not mistakenly flash it instead of the intended drive.

Now, here’s where things get fuzzy. I believe I came back, saw it had failed again, and shelved that for time being, shutdown Windows, and between then and when Windows was booted next, was able to access the LUKS partition w/o issue.  When I booted back into Windows later on—with the ‘Luks’ drive still plugged in, but I think the drive that wouldn’t be flashes was no longer—I think the balenaEtcher session was saved as I recall seeing it still saying ‘flash attempt failed’ after which I closed that window either then or later on.

Then this morning, I find out that the ‘Luks’ drive got (successfully) flashed, and also tested the other drive that supposedly hadn’t been, where in fact it too had been successfully flashed with the same OS. … I agree that the likely cause of the Luks drive being flashed was due to having it mistakenly selected in balena.

I’m really quite sure I did not select it though. For the 2nd attempt, I confirmed the correct disk by reading start of its label, as it was pre-selected from clicking ‘try again’. … the two drives’ start with different, easily distinguishable labels and are different sizes, so I’m almost positive I didn’t have a brain-go-brrr moment here, but I guess you never know. Maybe it decided to select both disks on the 2nd go? I’m 99.99% sure I chose only the intended drive for first pass.
Any thoughts re possible explanations beyond human error? More so out to satisfy my insatiate incredulity..

Answer (score 0):

> On an flash drive with 7.1 GB useable storage, I had a LUKS partition (2nd partition) of around 3.1GB, IIRC. A linux FS flashing using balena deleted that

Be specific. Is "that" the 2nd partition?

> and the 1st partition, with the OS partition flashed is 2.2GB. (At end of post is how that seemed to have happened, which I am at a loss for—not directly relevant though.)

> If the above is not drastically incorrect (doubtful), the 2nd partition including its header should be recoverable. …

How should that be if you overwrote the 2nd partition?

Maybe i have missed something, but your post is missing how your system behaves if you want to mount your encrypted LUKS partition.

The whole text afterwards does not provide any help for recovery purposes.

As the LUKS format is well-defined and you are unsure about your actions you could try verify if the LUKS header is still in place.

https://gitlab.com/cryptsetup/cryptsetup/-/wikis/LUKS-standard/on-disk-format.pdf

Just search for the fingerprint "LUKS". It has to be at the beginning of the partition in question, followed by the hex values 0xBA,0xBE.

[...
**LUKS_MAGIC {’L’,’U’,’K’,’S’,
0xBA,0xBE}
partition header
starts with magic**
...]

If the fingerprint is gone, you probably erased the header. You would require a backup header to recover your partition.

Comment: I cleared out my earlier comments to this, and posted about where I'm at currently in Unix&Linux stackexchange, as I think it is too far gone from the original post above. Link to new post: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/702558/recover-deleted-header-intact-luks-partition-loop-device-created-w-lomap-rej

Comment: Sudoplex, please post the solution you found here as to make your question comply to the question - answer scheme throughout StackExchange country. If you improved your problem description, update your question. All the rest - your solution - should reside here as an answer.  It is perfectly OK that you post the solution that you found.
Thank you!